# Issues with req.query, req.params, req.body using express+axios in MERN app

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios, request

I am trying to make the following call in React using axios:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/daily_batches/num_tweets_by_tag_and_date/`, {
            params: {
                tag: "Green/Sustainable Energy",
                date: "2021-05-07"
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
```

Should I use req.params, req.body or req.query in my express route for the axios call to be successful? If I use **req.params**, like so:

```
router.route('/num_tweets_by_tag_and_date/').get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const tag = req.params.tag; 
      const date = req.params.date;
      const tag_num_tweets_field = "tags." + tag + ".num_tweets"
      const num_tweets_data = await DailyBatch.findOne({"date": date}, {[tag_num_tweets_field]: 1, "_id": 0});
      res.json(num_tweets_data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(400).json({
        errors: {
          global: "An error occurred."
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

I get a "data:null" as shown in this screenshot. And indeed by doing console.log(req.params.tag) and console.log(req.params.date) in the route I get "undefined"
[image]

If I use **req.body.tag** and **req.body.date** instead of req.params.tag and req.params.date, I still get "undefined" when I console.log(date) and console.log(tag). And the api response is still "data:null". However, in Insomnia the api call works just fine and returns the expected data, as shown in the pic below:
[image]

If I use **req.query.date** and **req.query.tag**, I successfully get the data in the axios api call I make in React. However, the call does not work in Insomnia, where I get "null".

I cannot seem to find a way to make the get call in React using axios and passing a dictionary with the call parameters, while at the same time being able to make calls to the same endpoint in Insomnia. The only way I found is to use **req.param("tag")** and **req.param("date")** but apparently it's deprecated and so I would not want to use that.

I have read multiple posts about req.params, req.body and req.query but the more I read about this the more I am getting confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably req.body.

req.params is used if you set up your route using variables, such as

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req, res)=>{})
```

you can `console.log(req.body)` to check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I stated in my question, I have already tried using req.body but it only works when I make the call to the endpoint from Insomnia. When I make the call in React using Axios, req.body is undefined.

Comment: try changing params to data. 

also see the first example here: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Answer (score 0):

req.params is used when you have dynamic route .
Example= /:num_tweets_by_tag_and_delete
check here: [Node.js: req.params vs req.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976172/node-js-req-params-vs-req-body/24976217)